# Member function Row

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried running the query in my script and receiving this message. Anyone know why AND how to fix it.

Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object

```
$query_str = "SELECT MAX(userID) FROM kowmanager_users";
$this->db->query($query_str);

$row = $query->row(); 
$userID = $row->userID;
```

Edit:

I found the syntax for this here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select

And came up with this for my needs but when I ran the script it gave me a You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Object' at line 1

Filename: /home/xtremer/public_html/kowmanager/models/user_model.php

```
$this->db->select_max('userID');
$query_str = $this->db->get('kowmanager_users');
$rows = $this->db->query($query_str);
$userID = $rows->userID;
$userID = $userID + 1;
```

Edit 2:

For some reason the update isn't running.

```
 $query_str = "INSERT INTO kowmanager_users (username, password, password2, email, firstName, lastName, accessLevelID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $this->db->query($query_str, array($username, $password[0], $password[1], $email, $firstName, $lastName, '1',));

    $id = $this->db->insert_id();

    $this->db->select_max('userID');
    $query = $this->db->get('kowmanager_users');
    $row = $query->row();
    $userID = $row->userID;
    echo $userID;
    echo "<br>";
    $userID = $userID + 1;
    echo $userID;

    $data = array('userID' => $userID);

    $where = "id = '".$id."'"; 

    $str = $this->db->update_string('kowmanager_users', $data, $where);
```

Edit: Here's my full page code:
http://pastebin.com/7sJt7V09

Comment: Its only going to return the max userID from the query so it'll only be 5 digits like 10001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First effort should have been more like this:

```
$query_str = "SELECT MAX(userID) FROM kowmanager_users";
$q = $this->db->query($query_str);
$row = $q->row(); 
$userID = $row->userID;
```

Your second try should be this instead:

```
$this->db->select_max('userID');
$q = $this->db->get('kowmanager_users');
$row = $q->row();
$userID = $row->userID;
```

If you were returning more than one row, then you would do this kind of thing:

```
$this->db->select('userID');
$q = $this->db->get('kowmanager_users');
$results = $q->result();
foreach($results as $row) 
{
 echo $row->userID; 
}
```

Comment: Only problem is I run into an issue with the update. Check the last edit of my post.

Comment: for the update, I think you have only created the string. You still need to put that query string into an actual query: `$my_update = $this->db->query($str);`

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
$row = $this->db->query->row();
```

Comment: For some reason that didn't help.